# DynamoDB query with Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm really struggling to make queries work. I'm trying to get all items with primary key ('keyword') equal to 'compost spoons'.

This is one of my items:

```
{
  "keyword": "compost spoons",
  "created_at": "2020-08-12T11:31:21+00:00"
}
```

And this is the params in my query:

```
params = {
    table_name: "servings", 
    select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES", 
    return_consumed_capacity: "INDEXES",
    key_condition_expression: "keyword = :keyword_val",
    expression_attribute_values: {
        "keyword_val" => "compost spoon"
    }
  }
```

Error that it throughs:

```
"ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid key: Syntax error; key: \"keyword_val\""
```

What should be the params in order for the query to work?

The schema:

```
{
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "keyword",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "created_at",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "TableName": "servings",
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "keyword",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    },
    {
      "AttributeName": "created_at",
      "KeyType": "RANGE"
    }
  ],
  "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
  "CreationDateTime": "2020-08-14T10:26:55.528Z",
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "LastIncreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "LastDecreaseDateTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 5,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 5
  },
  "TableSizeBytes": 168,
  "ItemCount": 3,
  "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ddblocal:000000000000:table/servings"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a colon in front of your `keyword_val` in the `expression_attribute_values`.  I believe it should be:

```
params = {
    table_name: "servings", 
    select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES", 
    return_consumed_capacity: "INDEXES",
    key_condition_expression: "keyword = :keyword_val",
    expression_attribute_values: {
        ":keyword_val" => "compost spoon".  // <---- CHANGE IS HERE!!
    }
  }
```